# Predicate usually used for array/list how about here?

Tags: c#

In following code (Josh Smith's article on MVVM), can somebody give me some insight about
**return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);** ?

it is a normal if/else statement but I'm not getting the last part of it.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;        

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;           
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found a similar question but it doesn't explain that much about `_canExecute(parameter)` so will appreciate it if you guys let me know what is the deal with `_canExecute()` in ELSE section of condition block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_canExecute` is lambda function, and it can be null, depending on which constructor will instantiate `RelayCommand` object. Thus, the implementation of `CanExecute` method checks whether this function is set, and if it's not, it returns `true`, wheras if there is function assigned, it evaluates it (given the `parameter`), and the evaluated value is returned as a result for `CanExecute`.

In a nutshell: `CanExecute` will be evaluated using whatever predicate is passed along in the constructor, and in case of lack one - will always return `true`.

You've asked that's usually used for array/lists - it's very similar situation. The predicate is just a function that you can pass around. When you pass such predicate to some method that is filtering a collection, the method is just calling this predicate as it would any other function.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as shorthand:

```
if(_canExecute == null) 
{
    return true;
} 
else 
{
    return _canExecute(parameter);
}
```

In context, _canExecute is whatever your Predicate is from RelayCommand.